# Tomcat fails to start because of jdbc driver loading

Tags: jdbc, tomcat6

Here's the relevant portion of the tomcat startup log:

```
SEVERE: Context [/f360] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 8, 2010 6:45:56 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Apr 8, 2010 6:45:56 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Apr 8, 2010 6:45:56 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

The problem that it causes is that it basically causes the web app to fail to startup properly.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Startup failed due to *previous* errors. Please update your question to include those errors. They are the **root cause** of this problem.

Comment: The problem is that there are no errors listed before that. There are only INFO messages.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly this is a bug in the JDBC provider stack.  But anyway, I used some similar code in Jetty:

```java
public class CleanupContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("CleanupContextListener");
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
            ClassLoader driverclassLoader = driver.getClass().getClassLoader();
            ClassLoader thisClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            if (driverclassLoader != null && thisClassLoader != null &&  driverclassLoader.equals(thisClassLoader)) {
                try {
                    logger.warn("Deregistering: " + driver);
                    DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {}    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, especially when using Spring application on Tomcat, the error message is misleading - when there is no relation to any JDBC driver error at all but only a failure of some application BEAN init-method (or @PostConstruct).
The error stack trace is hidden and appears only in tomcat/logs/localhost.xxx
file.
Just be aware of this behavior.
It costed me a lot of time.

Regards,
Yosi Lev

Comment: This is true. When deploying my Grails application (which uses the Spring Framework) it has the database password compiled in the conf/DataSource.groovy file. Of course I was using the wrong password but the only error reported was this bizarre registration of the JDBC driver. No other database error is logged. There must be an option for Spring to log verbose all database startup operations.

Comment: It is true.The real reason is nothing about jdbc.

Comment: This cost me hours! Thanks Yosi Lev

Answer (score 5):

If it's the DBCP problem then stop tomcat, kill any remaining process (in case you have more than one tomcat running), delete the tomcat temp directory (and perhaps work directory) and try again.

Comment: This really helped me.  I tried killing tomcat, rebooting, everything.  When I shut down, deleted the temp dir, and then started back up, everything worked :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The SEVERE messages regarding JDBC drivers are caused by a DBCP issue. See [DBCP-332](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-332)

Comment: where is DBCP part of? Tomcat? I have above error with Tomcat6/JDK6/MacOS X, but it (same application, using postgres+jdbc) runs fine on Tomcat/JDK6/WinXP. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the reference rgielen. That explanation made sense.