# Tomcat 7: the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered

Tags: grails, groovy, tomcat7

I have some problems with deploying Groovy & Grails application on Tomcat 7.

There is my configuration:

```
Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.8
JVM Version: 1.6.0_26-b03
JVM Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS Name: Linux
OS Version: 2.6.32-32-server
OS Architecture: amd64
Grails: 1.3.8
Groovy: 1.8.0
```

On server there is 5 different application all runing and using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, but when I want to deploy one more application I ger this error:

> SEVERE: The web application [/RacuniWeb_v3-0.1] registered the JDBC
>   driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the
>   web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Can anyone help me ? What to do that deploy will work ?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered).

Comment: Your application is not getting deployed. This message is irrelevant as to why. Check messages before it.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this message when the tomcat jdbc driver is in your grails app. (inside the lib) folder. When you place the jdbc driver in the tomcat lib folder instead of inside the application lib folder this message will disappear.