# Sonar Configuration Error

Tags: oracle, maven, build, sonarqube

> Sonar plugin fails to execute
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL
>   driver not found org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver  at
>   org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverDatabaseConnector.getConnection(DriverDatabaseConnector.java:91)
>   at
>   org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.testConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:185)
>           ... 42 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

When I run sonar maven plugin with -X switch, I can see in the logs the following line:
`[DEBUG]  To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] has been forcibly deregistered`

I am assuming this is causing sonar to use `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` which it should as per my configurations. I have commented the lines to deactivate the default embedded derby DB in properties file. My `sonar.properties` have following content:

```
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:oracle:thin:@sagarmal05:1521:sonardb
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
sonar.jdbc.maxActive:                      10
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle:                        5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle:                        2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait:                        5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis:     600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis:  30000
sonar.jdbc.dialect=oracle
```

Also, I have environment variable set for maven as `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx700m -XX:MaxPermSize=420m`.
Interesting thing is when I tried to run the sonar execution on other machine the same configurations and same DB, it worked. Only thing different is variable `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx890m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. I can not set it as 890 and 512 on my machine due to memory crunch. If I do maven fails at startup shouting:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM. Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap. Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Help to get me understand what the exact problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is sonar server and there is the analysis of project using maven plugin.  `sonar.properties` is for sonar server. Is sonar server running fine?  maven plugin comes into picture later.

Comment: Yes sonar server has started all right and i can see it using oracle dialect in the logs.Database dialect class org.sonar.jpa.dialect.Oracle

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered