# Web app and Tomcat 7 Memory Leak

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler, tomcat7, visualvm

I am (test) running my web app in Tomcat 7 and using their "Find Leak" button and of course it complains about memory leak when I stop / undeploy.

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed),
>   but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus
>   causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm):
>   /LeakyWebApp

So I used Java VisualVM (my first time trying this out)

**on Tomcat startup with no deployment:**
http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/4441/tomcatstartup.jpg

My web app involves:

- Quartz 1.8.5
- Hibernate 3.6.3
- JAXB 2.2.4
- Salesforce API
- log4j

**Immediately after deployment:** http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2951/tomcatafterdeployment.jpg

So I noticed it complains about Quartz and I also read somewhere to close Hibernate Session Factory on servlet destroy.

On stop / undeploy, The Visual VM does show the Quartz thread stopped, but the tomcat log says

> "appears to have start a thread named ... and has failed to stop it"

So I created a new ServletContextListener and on contextDestroyed I call to Quartz factory scheduler to shutdown and also call close on Hibernate Session Factory. and doing another deploy/undeploy, there's no more complain from the tomcat log about Quartz thread problem as above.

However, when I use "find leaks" it still complains about the same thing

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed),
>   but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus
>   causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm):
>   /LeakyWebApp

Then i found another complain about JDBC driver (I have mysql connector jar in my war), so I tried removing that, the complain from tomcat log disappear but the "Find Leaks" still say the same thing that my web app has memory leaks

So my question would be - what else should I be looking at? and/or how can I use the Visual VM better to detect what's going?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I fixed the issue with Quartz based on the post by David Feitosa, I was missing

```
 <init-param>
     <param-name>wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

from the Quartz properties in web.xml.

However - I still have issue with the JDBC driver - I need it for my web app, and seems like I have 2 solutions based on the answers from: [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)

1. Put the mysql-connector jar in the tomcat/lib
2. Manually un-register the driver in the contextDestroyed.

Which way should I go and what's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the problems with memory leaks that I found in this kind of web app is related to Quartz. In order to solve this, try to use the proper Quartz Servlet to init the factory: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html

As in the Quartz doc, try to use:

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>
         QuartzInitializer
     </servlet-name>
     <display-name>
         Quartz Initializer Servlet
     </display-name>
     <servlet-class>
         org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>
         1
     </load-on-startup>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>config-file</param-name>
         <param-value>/some/path/my_quartz.properties</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
 </servlet>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks, I was only missing the "wait-on-shutdown" property and it fixes the issue. But, I still have an issue with the JDBC driver "[leakyApp] register a JDBC driver but failed to unregister it" - this comes from the fact that I have mysql-connector-java.jar in my web app, but I can't remove it because I need it - what can I do for this problem?

Comment: Unhappy, I have no clues for the driver problem yet. If I find, I return here.  Did you could look in your server documentation? Maybe using a DataSource object as in Tomcat or JBoss can solve your problem with the driver.

Comment: HI i am facing the same problem,but how can i add this Servlet to the my application ..can i create new servlet class,and deploy the war file into tomcat.. will it be success....