# Apache tomcat error with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I have a question in reference to Apache Tomcat.  I thought I knew what the issue was, but I will ask anyone who knows as a reference.

I am working on a web application that makes numerous database calls for information manipulation.  The application is connected to a MySQL server via straight jdbc.

I have checked and may have possibly missed, but all of my resultSets, statements, and connections are closed when the methods are completed as far as I can tell.  Yet, I get this recurring and troubling message from tomcat every time.  The message is as follows:

> SEVERE: The web application [/myApplication] registered the JDBC
>   driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the
>   web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver
>   has been forcibly unregistered. Sep 11, 2013 12:33:40 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>
> SEVERE: The web application [/myApplication] appears to have started a
>   thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to
>   stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Sep 11, 2013
>   12:33:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload.

If anyone has any insight into exactly what this this issue is, it would be most appreciated. If it helps, I have connections to 4 different databases within the MySQL database, I don't known whether or not that makes a difference, but just throwing it out there.

Thanks all.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered

Comment: Thanks for the referral.  This one has been bugging me for a while.