# whenever i update in servlet ,i found Memory Leak in tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, memory-leaks, quartz-scheduler

i am using the tomcat 6.0 for my web application.
i have used following technology in my project.

1. quartz
2. jasper reports
3. Birt Reports
4. hibernate
5. MySQL for backhand.

now problem is that if i update something in my servlet and if my server is running it started that memory leak error.
[image]

Comment: Faced a similar issue when added Qaurtz to my enterprise application. It seems that Quartz leaves some threads flying around. Fixed when updated to `try-with-resources`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a thread in your application which runs indefinitely when it is getting deployed and keeps running. May be you are starting a thread in the `ContextListener` ex: `ServletContextListener`. In your case, it may be `MySql` driver causes this problem. If you set the option `Build Automatically` in your IDE say `Eclipse`. Whenever you make changes in your class file, your application will be compiled, build and deployed in the server again. The other thing you should note is *if you have JDBC jar in your WEB-INF/lib, then move it to the tomcat server lib and restart the server*. This helps in de-registering the JDBC driver in JVM level.then, you will not be getting this message

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered), this will give you more options to resolve it.

Comment: but i have closed all the connection in that class finally blog.

Comment: `Finally` can not be trusted as such

Comment: finally will execute once class lifetime over..@saif Asif

Comment: how i can recover from this problem...?

Comment: Whiich JDK are you using ?

Comment: i am using  jdk1.6.0_29 @Saif Asif

Comment: Did you move your jdbc jar to TOMCAT's /lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz may start unmanaged threads. Check this link:

http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-194

Comment: but even i am remove all quartz code, 
it gives me same error.