# Glassfish warnings in new project

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

When i am creating new WEB project in NetBeans and running generated index.html page i get warnings:

```
WARNING:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/vovan_000/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebSite/target/WebSite-1.0-SNAPSHOT/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.

WARNING:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

And also Java DB service starting:

```
Sat Feb 15 12:29:15 EET 2014 : DRDA_SecurityInstalled.I
Sat Feb 15 12:29:20 EET 2014 : Сетевой сервер Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.3.0 - (1405108) запущен и готов принимать соединения на порту 1527 на {3}
```

But i have not any glassfish-web.xml in WEB-INF folder. And i am not using database and have not JDBC drivers.

How can i get rid of this warnings and disable java DB service starting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one:

> WARNING:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive
>   /C:/Users/vovan_000/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebSite/target/WebSite-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,
>   as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in
>   the same archive.

Just remove the file `sun-web.xml` because it is not needed if you deploy to GlassFish. If you have any required settings/declarations in the `sun-web.xml` you can migrate them to a `glassfish-web.xml`.

For this one:

> WARNING:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
>   application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
>   been forcibly unregistered.

This can happen if there is a JDBC4 driver in the web applications `WEB-INF/lib` folder, it looks like there is MySQL driver deployed with your web app. This is not really a problem, you can get some details about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered). 
To solve this you can move the MySQL driver jar to the folder `GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib`. If you use Maven make sure to set the MySQL driver dependency to scope **provided**.

For the last one:

> Sat Feb 15 12:29:15 EET 2014 : DRDA_SecurityInstalled.I Sat Feb 15
>   12:29:20 EET 2014 : Сетевой сервер Apache Derby Network Server -
>   10.8.3.0 - (1405108) запущен и готов принимать соединения на порту 1527 на {3}

In NetBeans go to the **Services** tab, open **Servers**, right-click your GlassFish instance and click **Properties**. Uncheck `Start Registered Derby Server`.

[image: start derby server]

Comment: First warning has gone. Thank You!
Derby Server not starting till i restart NetBeans.

Comment: And jdbc warning has gone! :) Thank you very much! 
only derby setting resets every time i restart netbeans