# Tomcat throws "Error listenerStart" on startup

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have tried to run Tomcat6. 
It always throw following exception:

```
....
09:16:13,968 [main] INFO - SchemaUpdate | HHH000232: Schema update complete
Aug 25, 2014 9:16:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 25, 2014 9:16:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 25, 2014 9:16:15 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 25, 2014 9:16:15 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [File Reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 25, 2014 9:16:16 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 25, 2014 9:16:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10494 ms
```

I have used following

- Ubuntu system
- java version 1.6.0_31 OpenJDK Runtime Environment
  (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
- Apache Tomcat 6
- MySQL Server 5.5
- MySQL JDBC Connector: com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar
- Hibernate and JSP-Servlet

I have already removed my jbdc from {app_home}/lib to {tomcat_home}/lib, then restart Tomcat as I see in [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered/6576394)

Unfortunately, the error is still thrown.

After I get the error,
I can go to tomcat homepage but I get this message after trying to start myapp using the tomcat 6 manager interface:

```
"FAIL - Application at context path /myapp could not be started"
```

I cannot access the myapp server homepage

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

earist.

Comment: Share your catalina.log

Answer (score 1):

In the case of SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
there are no logs in catilina.out about the errors but you can find some logs in localhost.* log files.

remove the localhost.* log file for today's date from tomcat's log folder and try to start the tomcat again and at the same time tail the localhost log file. You will get some lead on the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the error "SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors" is not related to "clearReferencesThreads" warning?
I can read the find the real cause in the localhost.*log, right?

Comment: I also faced this error many times and was able to find the cause in localhost-*.log file ... replace * with the system date

Answer (score 0):

I found that is my mistake.
The Tomcat start normally.

The problem is that I do not have a permission on a location path.
The location is used to store some data for my app.

Thanks.