# how to unregister the jdbc driver in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my project i have configured the c3po connection pooling for hibernate.For that i have added the two jar files named as c3p0-0.9.1.jar and hibernate-c3po-3.32.jar.Below is my hibernate.cfg.

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">15</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">120</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">150</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">25200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>

Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
```

The reason for the memory leak is:`The web application [name] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.`
it doesn't affect my application.How to resolve this exception.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: What makes you think that its a memory leak issue ?

Comment: may be i missed out any properties or setting wrong value in the property

Comment: Yes but thats not memory leak. You are facing some issue in hibernate configuration. Change the heading for better understanding so that interested community members could help you.

Comment: the reason is:The web application [name] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Comment: Now since you have posted additional error message, this looks better. Please check this link for similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered