# Jenkins error: Authorization failed to svn in sonarqube.

Tags: mysql, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-5.0

I am using Jenkins 2.8 with Sonarqube Plugin 2.2.1. A week ago we had a problem with the sonar server and we get this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered). To solve the problem we decided to create a new mysql schema and link it with sonar server. 
We did something like this:

```
mysql –u root -plinux;
create database sonarqube2 character set utf8;
grant all privileges on sonarqube2.* to 'sonarsuer'@'localhost' identified by 'linux';
grant all privileges sonarqube2.* to 'sonaruser'@'%' identified by 'linux';
flush privileges;
```

Note: We used the same user we had in the old database

After update sonar.jdbc.url with the new data in sonar.properties and in Jenkins configuration we manage to deploy sonarqube again. Then, we tried to launch a SONAR job that we have already created before and we get this error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project cas: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java] failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://my_svn_server/svn/mycompanyxf/cas/trunk/src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://my_svn_server) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project cas: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java] failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://my_svn_server/svn/mycompanyxf/cas/trunk/src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://my_svn_server)
```

This is the whole stacktrace:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) @ cas ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.0.1
[WARNING] Invalid POM for org.samba.jcifs:jcifs-ext:jar:0.9.4, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
INFO: Default locale: "es_ES", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /u01/jenkins_home/jobs/SONAR - MC - Cas/workspace/trunk/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0.1
[INFO] [13:47:05.297] Load global referentials...
[INFO] [13:47:05.751] Load global referentials done: 458 ms
[INFO] [13:47:05.771] User cache: /home/tomcat/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [13:47:05.801] Install plugins
[INFO] [13:47:07.792] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [13:47:07.802] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://myserver:3306/sonarqube2?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
[INFO] [13:47:11.353] Initializing Hibernate
[ERROR] [13:47:15.591] No license for plugin views
[INFO] [13:47:16.958] Load project referentials...
[INFO] [13:47:18.003] Load project referentials done: 1045 ms
[INFO] [13:47:18.003] Load project settings
[INFO] [13:47:19.038] Loading technical debt model...
[INFO] [13:47:19.097] Loading technical debt model done: 59 ms
[INFO] [13:47:19.115] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [13:47:19.336] -------------  Scan CAS (Central Authentication Service)
[INFO] [13:47:19.339] Load module settings
[INFO] [13:47:21.334] Loading rules...
[INFO] [13:47:23.049] Loading rules done: 1715 ms
[INFO] [13:47:23.115] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [13:47:23.367] No quality gate is configured.
[INFO] [13:47:29.435] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [13:47:29.437] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 2 ms
[INFO] [13:47:29.437] Base dir: /u01/jenkins_home/jobs/SONAR - MC - Cas/workspace/trunk
[INFO] [13:47:29.437] Working dir: /u01/jenkins_home/jobs/SONAR - MC - Cas/workspace/trunk/target/sonar
[INFO] [13:47:29.438] Source paths: src/main/webapp, pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] [13:47:29.438] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] [13:47:29.439] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [13:47:29.439] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: es_ES
[INFO] [13:47:29.439] Index files
[INFO] [13:47:30.480] 36 files indexed
[INFO] [13:47:31.213] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] [13:47:31.213] Quality profile for js: Sonar way
[INFO] [13:47:31.300] JIRA issues sensor will not run as some parameters are missing.
[INFO] [13:47:31.392] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:32.089] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [13:47:32.094] 25 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [13:47:36.733] Java Main Files AST scan done: 4643 ms
[INFO] [13:47:36.733] 25/25 source files analyzed
[INFO] [13:47:36.746] Java bytecode scan...
[INFO] [13:47:37.302] Java bytecode scan done: 556 ms
[INFO] [13:47:37.305] Java Test Files AST scan...
[INFO] [13:47:37.306] 5 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [13:47:37.626] 5/5 source files analyzed
[INFO] [13:47:37.627] Java Test Files AST scan done: 321 ms
[INFO] [13:47:37.633] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [13:47:37.684] Package design analysis done: 51 ms
[INFO] [13:47:37.801] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 6409 ms
[INFO] [13:47:37.813] Sensor QProfileSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:37.819] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 6 ms
[INFO] [13:47:37.819] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [13:47:40.023] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 2204 ms
[INFO] [13:47:40.026] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:40.205] 6 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [13:47:45.590] 6/6 source files analyzed
[INFO] [13:47:48.499] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor done: 8473 ms
[INFO] [13:47:48.506] Sensor CoverageSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:48.507] Sensor CoverageSensor done: 1 ms
[INFO] [13:47:48.507] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:48.525] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 18 ms
[INFO] [13:47:48.525] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:48.557] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 32 ms
[INFO] [13:47:48.558] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:48.600] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 42 ms
[INFO] [13:47:48.600] Sensor FileHashSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:48.608] Sensor FileHashSensor done: 8 ms
[INFO] [13:47:48.610] Sensor CoberturaSensor...
[INFO] [13:47:48.616] parsing /u01/jenkins_home/jobs/SONAR - MC - Cas/workspace/trunk/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
[INFO] [13:47:49.078] Sensor CoberturaSensor done: 468 ms
[INFO] [13:47:49.078] Sensor SCM Sensor...
[INFO] [13:47:49.089] SCM provider for this project is: svn
[INFO] [13:47:49.089] Retrieve SCM blame information...
[INFO] [13:47:49.218] 36 files to be analyzed
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:04.240s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 12 13:47:54 CEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/955M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project cas: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java] failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://my_svn_server/svn/mycompanyxf/cas/trunk/src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://my_svn_server) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project cas: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java] failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://my_svn_server/svn/mycompanyxf/cas/trunk/src/main/java/net/mycompany/cas/CookieRetrievingCookieGeneratorPatch.java': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://my_svn_server)
```

Should I change aditional credential in Jenkins? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See [SonarQube 5.0 SCM support documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE50/SCM+support) for details on how to configure SVN authentication (which is what is failing here) using `sonar.svn.username` and `sonar.svn.password.secured`.

(side-note: SonarQube 5.0 is pretty old and known for having performance issues, you should really upgrade to latest/LTS version)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already checked these properties and they are ok, as I had it before.

Comment: I have just found the solution. It's not a solution as it becuase I did a workaround. I will update the question as soon I can

Comment: Hello,Iam facing same issue,do you know what was the issue.can you post the workaroud.