# putting JDBC drivers to tomcat's lib did not solved the server memory leak

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, memory-leaks

I am using Tomcat 7.0.72 and mysql 5.1.36, I get

```
SEVERE:The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. 
    To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

This problem is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered) and as it is suggested, I put JDBC driver to Tomcat's `lib`, but it did not solved the problem yet. Where is the problem? Please advise.

Comment: did you stop and start your server?

Comment: Yes, actually I did add a new server and the same problem