# Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 - Web app doesn't start

Tags: oracle, apache, tomcat, jdbc, ojdbc

I'am trying start my webapp on my tomcat manager, but it dowsn't up.
I'm reading log file of the webapp and I have thise error:

> 8-giu-2017 9.41.12 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   GRAVE: Error listenerStart
>   8-giu-2017 9.41.12 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   GRAVE: Context [/ImageProcessor] startup failed due to previous errors
>   8-giu-2017 9.41.12 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>   GRAVE: The web application [/ImageProcessor] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>   8-giu-2017 9.41.12 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   GRAVE: The web application [/ImageProcessor] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   8-giu-2017 9.41.12 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   GRAVE: The web application [/ImageProcessor] appears to have started a thread named [CommunicatorServer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that "oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser" 
thread is running and it is not stopping so Tomcat will show it as a memory leak.
You have to deregister the drivers manually. See the link below to get insight.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5315467/7083879