# Spring Restful api configured properly with spring java based configuration but tomcat not starting

Tags: spring, tomcat8

Please find below tomcat trace, everything configured properly but tomcat is not starting also not showing any error properly.

```
        2017-07-13 06:30:20,607] Artifact hoprepositoryweb:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:23.223 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    151 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    157 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jul 13 18:30:23 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    276 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.hop.config.Application]
    1757 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'hoporbitsapp'
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:25.098 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: hoporbitsapp
        ...]
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:25.273 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:25.279 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:25.392 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:29.163 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:29.242 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
    6822 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'hoporbitsapp'
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:30.298 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\pers\Talha docs\work\Tomcat2\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\webapps\manager]
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:30.379 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\pers\Talha docs\work\Tomcat2\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\webapps\manager] has finished in [80] ms
    7679 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hop.controller.IndexController.index()
    7684 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/user],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hop.controller.UserController.register(com.hop.model.UserModel)
    8154 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jul 13 18:30:23 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    8499 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8348 ms
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:31.819 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:31.821 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    8516 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jul 13 18:30:23 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    13-Jul-2017 18:30:31.886 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    [2017-07-13 06:30:31,909] Artifact hoprepositoryweb:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)

Comment: Please format your log output to make the question easier to read.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other errors in error log file?

Comment: Issue has been resolved, I had class of security config but didn't import it on main configuration class. Thanks