# forcibly unregistring JDBC driver to prevent memory leak(intellij idea)

Tags: java, jdbc

I imported a maven project and worked with it quite well until today. I have the following error when compiling the code:

```
The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]   but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

I've already tried putting the jar for the JDBC connector in the lib folder of tomcat and creating pool for this connection to work, but still the same error.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a compilation error

Comment: Yes. Do you have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: @soukaina read the question right under the **Linked** section title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered?noredirect=1&lq=1