# Can Not Deploy application on Tomcat 7.0.41 when upgrading to Primefaces 4.0

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I am getting this message when I run my web application. It builds fine but during deploying, It fails everytime by this error:

```
SEVERE: The web application registered the JDBC driver[oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Any help appreciated.

FYI: 
My pom.xml is:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.26</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.26</version>
      </dependency>        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following is full list of errors I have got in Tomcat log:

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: No Function 
Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: 
java.lang.String resolveWidgetVar(java.lang.String)
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 11, 2013 2:44:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 11, 2013 2:44:44 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find 
Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
Nov 11, 2013 2:44:44 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.
application.ApplicationFactory. 
SEVERE: The web application [/taams-web] registered the JDBC driver    
[oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application 
was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Comment: You can't possibly see that error during deployment because it is generated during undeployment. Also, it won't stop anything working. What, exactly, is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered) and this [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604630/tomcat-fails-to-start-because-of-jdbc-driver-loading) can help you

Comment: I am working on some project, and I was using primefaces 3.5 but wanted to upgrade it to 4.0. I have added the jar files but same project which was working fine on 3.5 with tomcat is now not deploying on it, So that is my concern at this moment. If You want I can give full error log which I got during deployment..

Comment: Are you keeping the same tomcat 7? Or are you using an upgraded version (from 6 to 7)?

Comment: No I am Keeping the same Tomcat 7.0.41

Comment: The error message is about JDBC library, not about PrimeFaces. Looks like something is wrong in your tomcat installation or you have removed another library in your pom.

Comment: I didn't remove anything from Pom file. And, I just changed the versions of Primefaces and Primefaces extension from 3.5 to 4.0.RC1 and also jsf-api and jsf-impl to 2.1.3

Comment: Weird, I have the same setup (sans the extensions) and it deploys just fine. Are you sure you don't have duplicate libraries deployed in your web application? This smells like an old version of Primefaces and PF 4.0 both existing in the application at once. BTW: you're linking to a release candidate version, use version 4.0 to link to the final version.

Comment: I tried 4.0 too, I have double checked and In dependencies I have only Primefaces 4.0 and primefaces extension 1.0.0 that's it. If there is some other jars which are related to it then I am not sure But Yes, Its Kind of weired Its not deploying stuffs and Same stuffs is getting deployed if I use Primefaces 3.5 and Primeface extension 0.6.3. So It means, There is no issue in code which I have but may be smth I am missing here ..