# When I deploy my application, an error is occured. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

1. I created a model `RequisitionDetail`.
2. It has some properties, such as: `requisitionId` (a foreign key on requisition table), `productId` (a foreign key on product table), `quantity`, `unitPrice`, `totalPrice`.
3. When I declare annotation **@ManyToOne** or **@OneToOne** and deploy the code, I have this error.
4. Without declared **@ManyToOne** or **@OneToOne** annotation my application is deployed Successfully.
5. How to solve this problem?

**I Attach the Code Bellow :**
Class Name: ***RequisitionDetail.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "requisition_details")
public class RequisitionDetail {    
@Id
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(name = "requisition_id")
private Long requisitionId;
@OneToOne
@Column(name = "product_id")
private Long productId;   
private int quantity;   
@Column(name = "unit_price")
private Double unitPrice;
@Column(name = "total_price")
private Double totalPrice;
```

}

Comment: This error in your title is the result of your web application stopping, it is not the cause. Please provide a [mcve], give your question a better title and check your logs for an earlier error and include its full stacktrace in this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636800/3003337

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)